# WSO2 APIM : Get API Rating and Business Information through Store REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a custom page where I obtain Published API list using WSO2 Store Restful API 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/apidocs/store/#!/operations#APICollection#apisGet

The problem is the returned result does not includes API Rating and Business Information whereas the Jaggery API that has been used by the default API Manager UI does include it. Is there any way to configure it so the REST API returns that data?

If I use the jaggery API instead, it is cookie based while I am using OAuth2 OIDC Service Provider of the IS. I cant obtain API that has visibility to only its own domain by passing access token to the Authorization header.

**APIM Version: 2.2**

Please Advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a way which will change the output response of defined APIs.
If you want to do that, get source code of wso2 from github & edit the APIs & use the edited source to deploy your application. (But this will add lots of maintenance issue)

The quickest way is to call the [get details of api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/apidocs/store/#!/operations#APIIndividual#apisApiIdGet).

It will return the business information object as well as below:

```
"businessInformation":    {
      "technicalOwner": "John Doe",
      "technicalOwnerEmail": "architecture@pizzashack.com",
      "businessOwner": "Jane Roe",
      "businessOwnerEmail": "marketing@pizzashack.com"
   },
```

Here you will get the heavy response as it returns the complete swagger definition as well.

Comment: This API does not include the rating. any API to use to get the API star rating? I saw this one https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Rating+with+REST+API not sure this is the right one. If it is the right one, I dont know the resource path.